# Asus WiFi Driver for 13.10 (requires patch to work with kernel 3.11)

Tags: wireless, software-installation

I am new to Ubuntu and need help installing a WiFi driver for a ASUS PCE n53 wireless card.

I have read the instructions on the install disk and could not understand what I am to do.

I have also read a bunch of the posts about how to install it and that it needs a patch to work.  But I don't know what I am to download and how to apply it.

Have no idea what I am doing and don't want to mess something up.
My setup is the following:

- Dual boot with Ubuntu 13.10 & Windows 7.
- [MSI Z87-G43](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/Z87-G43.html)
- [Intel® Core™ i7
  Processor](http://www.intel.com.au/content/www/au/en/processors/core/core-i7-processor.html)
- 16 GB RAM
- [nvidia GeForce GTX Graphic
  Card](http://www.nvidia.com/object/geforce_family.html)
- [ASUS PCE-N53 Dual-Band Wireless-N600 PCI-E Adapter](http://www.asus.com/Networking/PCEN53/)
- `lspci -nn | grep 0280` showed:

  ```
  04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:5592]`
  ```

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Answer (score 0):

Install ndiswrapper

```
sudo install ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-modules-1.9 ndiswrapper-utils-1.9
```

Install the WiFi driver (from Windows):

```
sudo ndiswrapper -i yourdriver.inf
```

Check the driver is working:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -l
```

Load the module:

```
sudo depmod -a

sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
```

Configure modprobe so that it loads ndiswrapper:

```
sudo ndiswrapper -m
```

Edit the modules to add ndiswrapper at the end:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modules
```

Remember to add ndiswrapper at the end.

Hope you now have your WiFi up and working!

Comment: ndiswrappr is seldom the best solution; it is the solution of last resort.

Comment: I have read some of the posts and have noted ndiswrappr way of install limits the speed of the connection. But I will try this when I get home. Thanks

Comment: nate@Ubuntu1:~$ sudo install ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-modules-1.9 ndiswrapper-utils-1.9
[sudo] password for nate: 
install: target ‘ndiswrapper-utils-1.9’ is not a directory

Comment: any other ways you know of?